# Not able to login in my phpmyadmin

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin

Could not able to loggin in phpmyadmin after writing a single line of code at the TOP of index.php under phpmyadmin folder.But now i have deleted that single line of code. It is giving me the following error after providing credential-->

```
#0  PMA_sendHeaderLocation(http://linux.mydomain.com/phpmyadmin/index.php?token=8515d1390fbb0db27bebe4abd0668791) called at [/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/auth/cookie.auth.lib.php:612]

#1  PMA_auth_set_user() called at [/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php:828]

#2  require_once(/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php) called at [/phpmyadmin/index.php:35]
```

Please help me.

Comment: @ajreal: thx for making it readable

Comment: You probably left a space in front of the file (before `<?`)

Comment: Its solved.Thanks Pekka...I love u all....thanks a ton..God Bless...

Answer (score 0):

If you have any spaces in your code at the start of the file, PHP may interpret these to mean put these onto the browser. Doing so causes problems with the `header()` function as this needs to be the first thing output to the browser for it to work properly. Make sure there are no spaces before or after the